# Will this generate a random prize drawing

Tags: c#

Ive taken over some prize drawing code.

I can see the person is using a Random number to order them by but is this actually going to be random as i cant see any place where he has done oRand.Next(); Does the default Random generate an actual random number.

```
  Random oRand = new Random();


    var res = (from l in listNew.AsQueryable<Participant>() //entities.Participant
              where l.Status != 0                 
              select l).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(p=>oRand);
```

Comment: Mate, if this is for _real_ prize drawing code, you may want to check local legislation on the matter. At least in some jurisdictions, this would not cut the mustard with gaming regulation authorities. They want _true_ randomness.

Comment: If you need more details on the .NET Random class (e.g. for discussions regarding said local legislation), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx has a reference to the algorithm implemented - Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the default Random generate an
>   actual random number.

In the example code you are ordering by the "RandomNumberMaker" (i.e. the same value for all values), not by random numbers.

This is quickly tested by comparing this code in LINQPad (which yields the numbers 1 to 1000 in natural order).

```
void Main()
{
 Random oRand = new Random(); 
 var res = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).OrderBy(p=>oRand); 
 res.Dump();
}
```

with this code (which orders the numbers 1 to 1000 in **pseudorandom** order):

```
void Main()
{
 Random oRand = new Random(); 
 var res =Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).OrderBy(p=>oRand.Next()); 
 res.Dump();
}
```

For an intro to how random .NET random really is, check out [this article](http://www.csharpcity.com/how-random-is-random/) which has the advantage of starting with this great comic:

[image]
<sub>(source: [csharpcity.com](http://www.csharpcity.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Dilbert0001.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think you need oRand.Next() to get random numbers.  This looks like it would end up ordering them by the Random object.  I don't see how using oRand by itself would result in the lambda expression calling Next().

In any case, when you use `oRand = new Random(); oRand.Next();`, you get pseudorandom numbers using time as a seed.  This means that there is a sequence of numbers that is the same every time, and the one you start with depends on the time -- this is usually done with a function that you pass the last random number to get the next one and it has a very long period and the numbers have a random feel (so it's not just f(x) => x+1 or something like that).

This may not be good enough, but it is "random" for some definition of random.